# Formatting/bolding/filling cells with a value greater than 0

Tags: excel, vba

This is basically designed to format/bold/fill whatever cell has a value greater than 0. I would appreciate some help in simplifying it so that it doesn't lag as much.

```
Public Sub basesheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim icounter As Long
Dim wso As Worksheet
Dim rw As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

Set wso = Sheets("Base sheet(Oyin)")
    wso.Select
    lastrow = wso.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
            For icounter = 6 To lastrow
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 2) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 2).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 2).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 3) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 3).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 3).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 3).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 5) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 5).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 5).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 5).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If

                If wso.Cells(icounter, 6) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 6).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 6).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 6).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 6).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 7) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 7).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 7).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 7).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 7).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 7).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 14) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 14).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 14).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 14).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 14).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 14).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 16) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 16).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 16).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 16).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 16).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 16).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 17) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 17).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 17).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 17).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 17).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 17).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                 If wso.Cells(icounter, 18) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 18).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 18).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 18).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 18).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 18).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 19) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 19).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 19).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 19).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 19).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 19).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                  If wso.Cells(icounter, 20) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 20).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 20).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 20).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 20).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 20).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 21) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 21).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 21).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 21).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 21).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
wso.Cells(icounter, 21).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
If wso.Cells(icounter, 22) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 22).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 22).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 22).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 22).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 22).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 23) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 23).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 23).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 23).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 23).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 23).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 25) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 25).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 25).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 25).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 25).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 25).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 26) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 26).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 26).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 26).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 26).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 26).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
If wso.Cells(icounter, 27) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 27).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 27).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 27).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 27).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 27).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 28) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 28).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 28).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 28).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 28).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 28).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 29) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 29).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 29).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 29).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 29).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 29).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 30) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 30).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 30).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 30).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 30).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 30).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                 If wso.Cells(icounter, 31) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 31).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 31).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 31).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 31).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 31).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 10) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 10).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 10).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 10).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 10).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 10).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 24) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 24).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 24).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 24).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 24).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 24).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                 If wso.Cells(icounter, 4) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 4).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 4).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 4).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
 If wso.Cells(icounter, 8) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 8).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 8).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 8).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                 If wso.Cells(icounter, 9) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 9).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 9).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 9).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 11) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 11).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 11).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 11).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                   If wso.Cells(icounter, 12) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 12).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 12).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 12).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                 If wso.Cells(icounter, 13) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 13).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 13).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 13).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                 End If
                  If wso.Cells(icounter, 15) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 15).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 15).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
wso.Cells(icounter, 15).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous











                End If
            Next icounter

End Sub
```

Comment: works but is slow

Comment: did you try conditiona formatting instead of vba? This seems to be more suitable via conditional formatting.

Comment: I need it formatted so I can run another code that copies this data over to another sheet. I tried conditional formatting and it doesnt get copied over

Comment: @cyboashu - You can set font.bold and border with a CF rule but I do not believe you can set cell alignment.

Comment: Regarding the "lags too much" part - consider switching off `Application.ScreenUpdating` while processing (and turning it back on once done). Also you have a potential bug in `wso.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row` - `Rows.Count` should be `wso.Rows.Count`.

Comment: Nice job by @Jeeped and Thomasinzina below, they made it simpler in a way I couldn't quite figure out!

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way would be to filter the columns and apply the formatting to all the visible cells at once.  Don't forget to turn off ScreenUpdating when applying formats.

---

```
Public Sub basesheet()
    Dim TagetRange As Range
    Dim y As Integer, lastrow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Base sheet(Oyin)")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        With .UsedRange.Offset(1)

            With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .Font.Bold = False
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

        End With
        '
        For y = 2 To 31
            Set TagetRange = .Range(.Cells(2, y), .Cells(lastrow, y))

            TagetRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"    ', Operator:=xlAnd
            On Error Resume Next
            With TagetRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                Select Case y
                    Case 4, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15

                    Case 10, 24
                        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
                        .Font.Bold = True
                    Case Else
                        .Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                        .Font.Bold = True
                End Select
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            TagetRange.AutoFilter
        Next

    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I originally got caught on this as well. There are two columns that receive a different color combination and several that receive none at all.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks.  I checked for that, but must of missed it because  was itching to write the code...lol.

Comment: @Jeeped There were actually 3 different style sets. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Take this response along with the question to CodeReview.

Bulk operations are always faster than looping through individual cells. A [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) can be used to identify the cells with a value greater than zero and the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) can be used to isolate them for bulk operations.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub basesheet()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim c As Long, aCOLs As Variant

    'turn off some environment settings (uncomment once this runs to your satisfaction
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    aCOLs = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, _
                  18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31)

    With Worksheets("Base sheet(Oyin)")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 31))
            For c = LBound(aCOLs) To UBound(aCOLs)
                With .Columns(aCOLs(c))
                    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">0"
                    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                        If CBool(Application.Subtotal(102, .Cells)) Then
                            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                                Select Case aCOLs(c)
                                    Case 10, 24
                                        .Font.Bold = True
                                        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
                                    Case 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15
                                        'do nothing
                                    Case Else
                                        .Font.Bold = True
                                        .Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                                End Select
                                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                                .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                            End With
                        End If
                    End With
                    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
                End With
            Next c
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    'restore environment settings
    appTGGL


End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

I've added a 'helper' procedure that suspends certain application environment settings during the procedure's operation.

Comment: Actually the `.StatusBar = vbNullString` is intended to clear the status bar of any messages that were passed to it during processing; e.g. `5% done` in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with cyboashu that Conditional Formatting seems best for this scenario and not vba. However, I want to use this opportunity to point out a few VBA techniques that may help you in the future.

```
    lastrow = wso.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
            For icounter = 6 To lastrow
                If wso.Cells(icounter, 2) > 0 Then
                wso.Cells(icounter, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                wso.Cells(icounter, 2).Font.Bold = True
                wso.Cells(icounter, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 2).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                wso.Cells(icounter, 2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

If you're referring to a range as above, it can be faster to use the `For Each ... In ...` technique. Below is how I would rewrite the above code section

```
Dim Cell1 As Range 'add this to your above dimmed variables

    lastrow = wso.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    Set FormattingRange = wso.range(wso.Cells(6,2), wso.Cells(lastrow,2))
    For Each Cell1 in Formatting Range 
        If Cell1.Value > 0 Then
            With Cell1
                .Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End With    
        End If
    Next Cell1
```

As you can see, this technique also cuts down on the repetition of `wso.Cells(icounter, 2)`. This helps the speed also because Excel doesn't have to figure out which cell you are referring to each time - it knows from the `With Cell1` clause that you will refer to the same cell for the next several commands.

Finally, you need to turn off Calculation and ScreenUpdating using `Application.Calculation = xlManual` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of your code and then turn them back on with `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of it. Right now your code is re-calculating and updating the screen while you make all these formatting changes and slowing things down.